# Проблема аргумента ctx discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Пишу бота используя `disnake` и столкнулся с вопросом. Ниже две почти аналогичные функции:

```
@bot.slash_command(description='Очищает данное количесво сообщений.')
async def clear(ctx, reason: int = commands.Param(name="number_of_messages_to_clear")):    #slash-command clear
    print(ctx)
    await check_moderator_role(сtx=ctx)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(reason))
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=disnake.Embed(description=f'**{reason} сообщений(e) удалено!** :white_check_mark:'), delete_after=60)
```

---

```
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, reason):    #unslash-command clear
    print(ctx)
    await check_moderator_role(ctx=ctx)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(reason))
    await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(description=f'**{reason} сообщений(е) удалено!** :white_check_mark:'), delete_after=60)
```

В них прописаны две команды, обычная команда работает, слэш - нет.

Ошибка как я уже точно определил во второй строке функции, а именно в её аргументе - `await check_moderator_role(ctx=ctx)`

`check_moderator_role(ctx)` - моя сам описная функция, знать что в ней находится не обязательно, сама она рабочая, проблема с её аргументом.

Я выяснил, что аргумент `ctx` в разных функциях почему - то разный, в слеш - команде он равен: `<disnake.interactions.application_command.ApplicationCommandInteraction object at 0x000000000399F740>`, а в анслеш: `<disnake.ext.commands.context.Context object at 0x0000000003D0E6A0>`, *я думаю проблема в этом*.

### Вопрос такой: Почему аргумент `ctx` в разных функциях имеет разные значения и может ли из-за этого не работать функция?

Стек ошибки: `disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: check_moderator_role() got an unexpected keyword argument 'сtx'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам далеко не самый опытный но во первых, проверку на наличие нужной роли делайте через декоратор, во вторых, `ctx` не подходит в данном случае и вместо него нужно использовать `inter`.

```
@bot.slash_command(description='Очищает данное количесво сообщений.')
@commands.has_any_role('роль') #название вашей роли
async def clear(inter, reason: int = commands.Param(name="number_of_messages_to_clear")):    #slash-command clear
    await inter.channel.purge(limit=int(reason))
    await inter.response.send_message(embed=disnake.Embed(description=f'**{reason} сообщений(e) удалено!** :white_check_mark:'), delete_after=60)
```

Comment: inter это и есть ctx, просто другое название (проверил, не работает). Огромное спасибо что рассказали про декоратор)

Comment: У меня всё работает, какую ошибку выдаёт? inter != ctx

Comment: Та же самая. Это происходит потому что ошибка заключается именно в функции check_moderator_role(), а вы её убрали. Хотя почему бы мне не сделать так же?

UPD: Заработало)